# Combing multiple videos and audio tracks for playback in VLC

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player, video-editing, video-playback

I have multiple videos (about 5-10 minutes each) that I need to play together during a long presentation with an audio track (multiple files) over it. I created the separate videos for ease of editing and kept the audio track off them to allow for continuous playback.

Now my choices are to go back to the video editing software to combine all the videos and add the audio tracks to create one file, or figure out a way to just be able to do that in playback... is that possible in VLC? I do see other threads about overlaying a different audio track over a video in VLC, but I'm dealing with multiple video and audio files. Please help!